# asp.net Handler error - does not inherit from 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net

whenever I try to run my project, I get the following error:

```
  Error 19  Type 'CompressionModule' does not inherit from System.Web.IHttpHandler'.
```

Here is my module code

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web;

namespace SWMS
{
public class CompressionModule : IHttpModule
{
    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {
    }

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PostReleaseRequestState);
    }

    void context_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (app.Context.CurrentHandler is System.Web.UI.Page && app.Request["HTTP_X_MICROSOFTAJAX"] == null)
        {
            if (IsEncodingAccepted(GZIP))
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                SetEncoding(GZIP);
            }
            else if (IsEncodingAccepted(DEFLATE))
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                SetEncoding(DEFLATE);
            }
        }
    }

    private const string GZIP = "gzip";
    private const string DEFLATE = "deflate";

    private static bool IsEncodingAccepted(string encoding)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        return context.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"] != null && context.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"].Contains(encoding);
    }

    private static void SetEncoding(string encoding)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", encoding);
    }
}
}
```

I have used the following code to register my module

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="compression" type="SWMS.CompressionModule, SWMS "/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

can anyone please help me to understand what have I done wrong??

Comment: How are you registering your module?

Comment: I have registered In web.config file.. Wait i'll post the code

Comment: Your error says that `CompressionModule` does not inherit from `System.Web.IHttpHandler`.  The error is correct as it doesn't - it inherits from `IHttpModule`.

Comment: @MartinParkin so what Should I do for this?

Comment: @HarshShah, is this the only place were your module is mentioned in the application?

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from `IHttpHandler` and implementing methods it requires?

Comment: I guess. OP has re-write the whole code in .ashx

Comment: public class Handler : IHttpHandler

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour not working.. any other solution??

Comment: @Migol how do I inherit from IHttpHandler & what are the required methods to implement?

Comment: @Andrei i have used this module to call mu gzipped css file like this `../CompressionModule.ashx?id=master.css.gz`

Comment: @HarshShah, then it is HttpHandler you really need, not module